# Rotina não funciona

Tags: java, for

teno um laço para o usuário digitar o nome e idade do aluno. 
porém ao compilar, a primeira parte de pedir nome do aluno esta passando direto e ja cai perguntando a idade do aluno. segue o código básico.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int op = 1;
    String nome = "";
    boolean cadastrouAlunos = false;

    Alunos[] aluno = new Alunos[4];

    while (op != 0) {
        System.out.println("==============INFORME UMA OPÇÃO==============");
        System.out.println("1-CADASTRAR ALUNO");
        System.out.println("5-MOSTRAR ALUNOS");

        op = in.nextInt();

        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                for (int i = 0; i < aluno.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Informe o nome do aluno");
                    nome = in.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Informe a idade do aluno");
                    int idade = in.nextInt();

                    int codigo = i;
                    aluno[i] = new Alunos(nome, codigo, idade);
                    cadastrouAlunos = true;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if(!cadastrouAlunos){
                    System.out.println("Antes de tudo, cadastre todos seus aluno!");
                }else{
                    for (Alunos a : aluno) {
                        System.out.println("Aluno: " + a.nome);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Operação cancelada pelo usuário");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opção não válida");
        }

    }

}
```

a compilação fica assim:

```
INFORME UMA OPÇÃO
1-CADASTRAR ALUNO
5-MOSTRAR ALUNOS
1
Informe o nome do aluno
Informe a idade do aluno
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua `in.nextLine();` por `in.next();`

Answer (score 0):

Olá o colega esta a ter problemas de buffer então substitua a linha onde se faz a leitura do nome e coloque isto lá:

nome = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();